# Flink: Window evaluation

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using `window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(120), Time.seconds(1)))` sliding window for real_time streaming of data. I am also using the interface `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` to extract the timestamps and assign watermarks. I am applying the custom method `apply()` on windowed stream.

In this scenario, what will trigger the window evaluation(`apply()` execution), is it happened after every 1 sec. which is equal to slide of window or is it after encountering the watermark in the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window is evaluated when its end timestamp is smaller than the current watermark. When a window operator receives a new watermarks, it checks all active windows and finalizes all windows whose end time is before the new watermark.

If you have a window that slides by 1 second and watermarks that arrive approximately every five seconds, each watermark will trigger the evaluation of five windows. You can think of the watermark as a mechanism to set the clock of the application. If the operator does not know that the clock advanced, it will not perform a computation.

Comment: Hi, if I return the **NULL** watermark and use `window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(120), Time.seconds(1)))` then is the window evaluation happened after every 1 sec?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `null` watermark, but if the window operator does not receive valid watermarks it will not compute anything.

Comment: Hello Tumbling Windows https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#tumbling-windows say "the current window will be evaluated", does it mean every element will also write to sink before expire?